# Unable to access service in Pod on Kubernetes Windows node

Tags: kubernetes

I have setup a Kubernetes Windows Node. I set up the cluster network using flannel by following [this documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/SDN/tree/master/Kubernetes/flannel/l2bridge).

I can start pods on the windows node and I can also connect to the Windows node from the Linux master by using `kubectl exec`. I am running the [simpleweb](https://github.com/Microsoft/SDN/blob/master/Kubernetes/flannel/l2bridge/manifests/simpleweb.yml) webserver on the windows node. From a powershell inside the container I can also confirm that the webserver is running. So from all I can tell, basic connectivity is up and scheduling pods on the Windows node works.

However, I am unable to connect to the pod IP and port. I can neither connect from the Windows host nor from the Linux master.

My Windows Host IP is 172.33.1.150. The Pod on the Windows node is in the subnet 10.244.2.0/24 with IP 10.244.2.33. The cluster network that flannel sets up is the default 10.244.0.0/16.

Based on my current understanding the pod gets an IP in the cluster network (e.g. 10.244.2.33). Shouldn't I be able to access that IP and port 80 from the windows host?

I noticed, that the windows node has no network interface with a cluster IP, while my Linux node does have a network interface with a cluster IP (e.g. 10.244.1.1).

**Update:**
Using the `Get-HnsEndpoint` powershell command I can actually see that there exists an HNS interface for the network `10.244.1.0/24` on my windows node.

**Update 2:**
I discovered the following line in the logs of the my flannel containers:

> ignoring non-vxlan subnet(10.244.2.0/24): type=host-gw

**Update 3:**

`kubectl describe pod win-webserver-123456789a-abcde`:

```
Name:               win-webserver-123456789a-abcde
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               ec2amaz-1234567/172.33.1.150
Start Time:         Thu, 18 Oct 2018 13:06:11 +0000
Labels:             app=win-webserver
                    pod-template-hash=123456789a
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.244.2.83
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/win-webserver-123456789a
Containers:
  windowswebserver:
    Container ID:  docker://17b6415b05bc73443cbfc848bfd85015d03aa8448ee054232604348908cc0451
    Image:         microsoft/windowsservercore:1803
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://microsoft/windowsservercore@sha256:1095736efb6d27ca9a5c9df3ff399cab8130a2915f84c3a0b253480532878ecb
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      powershell.exe
      -command
      <#code used from https://gist.github.com/wagnerandrade/5424431#> ; $$listener = New-Object System.Net.HttpListener ; $$listener.Prefixes.Add('http://*:80/') ; $$listener.Start() ; $$callerCounts = @{} ; Write-Host('Listening at http://*:80/') ; while ($$listener.IsListening) { ;$$context = $$listener.GetContext() ;$$requestUrl = $$context.Request.Url ;$$clientIP = $$context.Request.RemoteEndPoint.Address ;$$response = $$context.Response ;Write-Host '' ;Write-Host('> {0}' -f $$requestUrl) ;  ;$$count = 1 ;$$k=$$callerCounts.Get_Item($$clientIP) ;if ($$k -ne $$null) { $$count += $$k } ;$$callerCounts.Set_Item($$clientIP, $$count) ;$$ip=(Get-NetAdapter | Get-NetIpAddress); $$header='<html><body><H1>Windows Container Web Server</H1>' ;$$callerCountsString='' ;$$callerCounts.Keys | % { $$callerCountsString+='<p>IP {0} callerCount {1} ' -f $$ip[1].IPAddress,$$callerCounts.Item($$_) } ;$$footer='</body></html>' ;$$content='{0}{1}{2}' -f $$header,$$callerCountsString,$$footer ;Write-Output $$content ;$$buffer = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($$content) ;$$response.ContentLength64 = $$buffer.Length ;$$response.OutputStream.Write($$buffer, 0, $$buffer.Length) ;$$response.Close() ;$$responseStatus = $$response.StatusCode ;Write-Host('< {0}' -f $$responseStatus)  } ;
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 18 Oct 2018 13:06:18 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-4l7tt (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-4l7tt:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-4l7tt
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  beta.kubernetes.io/os=windows
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

`ipconfig`:

```
Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Ethernet 3):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : eu-central-1.compute.internal
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : [...]
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.33.1.150
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.33.1.1

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (nat):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : [...]
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.29.160.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

`Get-HnsEndpoint` (brief):

```
IPAddress          : 10.244.1.16
IsRemoteEndpoint   : True
State              : 1
Type               : l2bridge
VirtualNetworkName : cbr0

DNSServerList             : 10.244.1.2
GatewayAddress            : 10.244.0.2
IPAddress                 : 10.244.2.82
PrefixLength              : 24
State                     : 1
Type                      : l2bridge
VirtualNetworkName        : cbr0

IPAddress          : 10.244.1.17
IsRemoteEndpoint   : True
State              : 1
Type               : l2bridge
VirtualNetworkName : cbr0

IPAddress          : 172.33.1.142
IsRemoteEndpoint   : True
State              : 1
Type               : l2bridge
VirtualNetworkName : cbr0

DNSServerList             : 10.244.1.2
GatewayAddress            : 10.244.0.2
IPAddress                 : 10.244.2.84
PrefixLength              : 24
State                     : 3
Type                      : l2bridge
VirtualNetworkName        : cbr0

DNSServerList             : 10.244.1.2
GatewayAddress            : 10.244.0.2
IPAddress                 : 10.244.2.83
PrefixLength              : 24
State                     : 3
Type                      : l2bridge
VirtualNetworkName        : cbr0
```

Comment: can you please add `kubectl describe pod` for Windows machine?

Comment: I added the output and also attached output of ipconfig and Get-HnsEndpoint.

Comment: Btw. I have already disabled the windows firewall on the machine.

Comment: My main problem with this issue is that I do not know how to debug this problem. On Linux I know a whole bunch of commands for debugging network issues. But on windows I am not very familiar with the details of HNS, Hyper-V switching and the general network configuration. I am not sure if debugging networking issues is generally more difficult on Windows than on Linux or if its just my lack of tool knowledge. In any case, it would certainly help me to learn which powershell commands can be used to debug this issue.

Comment: @aurelius Any ideas?

Comment: I had troubles with joining the windows node - because of my network restrictions, I succeeded finally, hope I can find something useful.